# Facebook Auth Provider status

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, auth-provider

I've successfully develop Facebook Single Sign-On. The question is: is it possibile to send a "status" parameter in the requesting URL?
I mean something like "https://test.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00DXXX00000XXXXXXX/MyFacebookProvider?status=XXXXX" ?
this whould be really helpfull because I need to create the User/Contact in the Auth.RegistrationHandler on certain conditions that not rely on Facebook OAuth response.
Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) suggests you can use the `state` parameter for this purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately this parameter is not passed "back" when calling the Auth.RegistrationHandler class